# Unfortunately App Has Stopped Still Facing After Adding Change To Manifest

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

Anyone Can Help me here

I am keeping suffering this problem 
I created my app and it runs awesome on some devices
But when I tried to run my signed apk in another phone the title problem caused 
I finish my javalangoutofmemory problem
By putting

`android:hardwareaccelerated="true"`
`android:largeheap`

In manifest
But still facing the title problem

Comment: please add the logCat of the crash statement

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this for tips on how to find the cause of the crash.

Comment: Do you have any other means of reducing your app memory consumption than that Manifest file directives?